# "Allow from xxx.xx.xx" in .htaccess not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this code in my .htaccess folder. This .htaccess folder is in the directory: /api/.htaccess
api.php location: /api/api.php

I have this code in the .htaccess:

```
<Files api.php>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from 122.109.32.241
Allow from 130.211.76.20
</Files>
```

My goal is to block every one but those IPs. The problem is that Im still getting 403 error even though my IP is on allow.

Error:

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /api/api.php on this server.
Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at accountdispenser.com Port 80

EDIT:
Ok after some playing around this method works: $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];

But how do I get the .htaccess to work with that method?

Comment: Is your IP address same as what the server is seeing?

Comment: How can I check this? I entered the IP I got from google when searching "See my ip"

Comment: You can make a test file on your server and see `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to verify. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php

Comment: Well that must be the problem. It comes up blank. It seems it can't get my IP.

Comment: Can't really be blank. Try any other answers on the question i linked. It can be a proxy address but can't be blank if there is no typo

Comment: Thats what I don't understand. Its just blank! No spelling errors and I'v tired them all.

Comment: Ok after some playing around this method works: $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];

But how do I get the .htaccess to work with that method?